# Two proof of Petersen's 'Manifold'

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, riemannian-geometry

Picture below is from the 5 page of Petersen's Manifold.

First, why diffeomorphism is forced to be a lieanr  isomorphism? The define of diffeomorphism accords to [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffeomorphism).

Second , what space the point $p$ is in ?And $A^n$ is a set or coordinate map ?

> [image]

Comment: The **differential** $d_pf$ of a diffeomorphism (at each point $p$) is forced to be a linear isomorphism. The diffeomorphism itself needn't be. Reason why the differential is a linear isomorphims: 1) $d_pf$ is a linear map by definition 2) It's an isomorphism because the composition rule holds $d_{f(p)}g\cdot d_pf=d_p(f\circ g)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^m$ is a diffeomorphism, then $f^{-1}:\Bbb R^m \to \Bbb R^n$ exists, and the equation $f^{-1}\circ f = {\rm id}$ gives $Df^{-1}(f(p))\circ Df(p) = {\rm id}$, whence $Df(p)$ has a left-inverse. Differentiating $f\circ f^{-1}={\rm id}$  at the point $f(p)$ gives that $Df^{-1}(f(p))$ is also a right-inverse for $Df(p)$, so $Df(p)$ is a linear isomorphism. This in particular forces $n=m$.

For the second part, the idea is to consider the set of points in $M$ that have coordinates using $n$ functions, that is $A^n$, and then check that $A^n$ is both open and closed in $M$. In details: $$A^n = \{ p \in M \mid \text{exists }U \subseteq \Bbb R^n \text{ open and a parameterization }\varphi\colon U \to M \text{ around }p\}.$$By connectedness of $M$, we'll have that $A^n = M$ for the $n$ satisfying $A^n \neq \varnothing$ (meaning that the dimension will be decided by one point). It really is clear that $A^n$ is open, so to see closedness, we take a convergent sequence in $A^n$ and see that the limit is in $A^n$ too. Suppose that $p_i \to p$. Since $p \in M$, there is a coordinate system around $p$ using $m$ functions, but $p_i \to p$, so that coordinate system works for $p_i$ too, for large enough $i$. But $p_i \in A^n$, so that coordinate system must actually use $m=n$ functions.

---

A linear isomorphism is a bijective linear transformation. Being bijective is equivalent to having both sided inverses. This is just linear algebra.

I'll elaborate more on your second question: since $p\in M$, there is an open set $p \in V \subseteq M$ and $U\subseteq R^m$ open such that we have a coordinate system $\varphi: U \to V$ around $p$. By definition of convergence, there is $i_0$ such that $p_i \in V$ for all $i \geq i_0$. Then $\varphi: U \to V$ is a coordinate system around $p_{i_0}$, for example, and now $p_{i_0} \in A^n$ implies $m=n$.

Comment: Whether it should be  $Df^{-1}(f(p))\circ Df(p) = \theta$?

Comment: why the map having left inverse and right inverse is linear isomorphism ? Which book teach about this ?

Comment: Secondly， what mean is "coordinate system works for $p_i$ too, for large enough $i$"

Comment: @lanse7pty I edited the answer elaborating a bit more on your questions, hope it helps.